# How to Push Kubernetes (EKS) Logs to Cloudwatch logs with separate log streams based on application name

Tags: kubernetes, fluentd, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-eks

I have a scenario where I need to push application logs running on EKS Cluster to separate cloudwatch log streams. I have followed the below link, which pushes all logs to cloudwatch using fluentd. But the issue is, it pushes logs to a single log stream only.

> https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-workshop-for-kubernetes

It also pushes all the logs under `/var/lib/docker/container/*.log`. How Can I filter this to can only application specific logs?

Comment: which workshop is this?

Comment: just google 'eksworkshop'

Answer (score 0):

[Collectord](https://collectord.io) now supports AWS CloudWatch Logs (and S3/Athena/Glue). It gives you flexibility to choose to what LogGroup and LogStream you want to forward the data (if the default does work for you).

- [Installation instructions for CloudWatch](https://collectord.io/docs/cloudwatch/kubernetes/installation/)
- [How you can specify LogGroup and LogStream with annotations](https://collectord.io/docs/cloudwatch/kubernetes/annotations/#override-loggroup-and-logstream)

Highly recommend to read [Setting up comprehensive centralized logging with AWS Services for Kubernetes](https://collectord.io/blog/2019-03-13-aws-centralized-logging-for-kubernetes/)